# how to used Custom Calendar view in android java

Tags: java, android

[I want to this type of calendar view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPBy3.jpg) 
Please any body help  me .

I am trying many time in google and github library also . I did not get. Please help me.

Nowadays in most of the apps, we see Calendar in most of the apps for displaying attendance dates using present date color and absent date color , we are going to make a custom calendar for our android application. In this custom calendar, we have highlighted the current date and other dates which seemed important to us.

Comment: Take a look at [this library](https://github.com/weblineindia/Android-Custom-Datepicker)